# C#/.NET: Reformatting a very long string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to read a string, character by character, and build a new string as the output.

What's the best approach to do this in C#?

Use a StringBuilder? Use some writer/stream?

Note that there will be no I/O operations--this is strictly an in-memory transformation.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve, an example would be helpful

Comment: Do you know the size of or your reformatted string in advance? If so, you should be able to create a `char[]` if the reformatted string size, put each char into it, then convert it back to a string with `new String(charBuffer)`.

Answer (score 5):

If the size of the string cannot be determined at compile time and it may also be relatively large, you should use a `StringBuilder` for concatenation as it acts like a mutable string.

```
var input = SomeLongString;

// may as well initialize the capacity as well
// as the length will be 1 to 1 with the unprocessed input.
var sb = new StringBuilder( input.Length );
foreach( char c in input )
{
    sb.Append( Process( c ) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if it's just one string you can use a collection to hold your characters and then just create the string using the constructor:

```
IEnumerable<char> myChars = ...;
string result = new string(myChars);
```

Using Linq and with the help of a method `ProcessChar(char c)` that transforms each character to its output value this could be just a query transformation (using the string constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<char>` as input):

```
string result = new string(sourceString.Select(c => ProcessChar(c)));
```

This is as efficient as using a `StringBuilder` (since `StringBuilder` is used internally in the string class to construct the string from the `IEnumerable`), but much more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Stringbuilder is usually a pretty good bet.  I've written lots of javascript in webpages using it.

Answer (score 0):

A `StringBuilder` is good idea for building your new string, because you can efficiently append new values to it. As for reading the characters from the input string, a `StringReader` would be a sufficient choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    string myLongString = "lf;kajsd;lfkjal;dfkja;lkdfja;lkdjf;alkjdfa";

    var transformedTString = string.Join(string.Empty, myLongString.ToCharArray().Where(x => x != ';'));

    transformedTString.Dump();
}
```

If you have more complicated logic you can move your validation to separate predicated method

```
void Main()
{
    string myLongString = "lf;kajsd;lfkjal;dfkja;lkdfja;lkdjf;alkjdfa";

    var transformedTString = string.Join(string.Empty, myLongString.ToCharArray().Where(MyPredicate));

    transformedTString.Dump();
}

public bool MyPredicate(char c)
{
    return c != ';';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's the difference between read string and output string? I mean why do you have to read char by char?

I use this method for reading string

```
string str = "some stuff";
string newStr = ToNewString(str);


string ToNewString(string arg)
{
   string r = string.Empty;
   foreach (char c in arg)
      r += DoWork(c);
   return r;
}

char DoWorK(char arg)
{
    // What do you want to do here?
}
```

Comment: And that would be about the worst way to do it.  You could potentially create *a ton* of copies in your loop and the OP mentions specifically that the string will be large.